# NLTK access local files; UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 834: char acter maps to <undefined>

Tags: python-3.x, cygwin, nltk, python-unicode

This is my first post and I have little to no experience but I like to learn.
I hope this post is comprehensible but please feel free to ask for further details.

I am working with Cygwin, and occasionally I use IDLE Python 3.9 to complete some tasks for University.
Currently I am trying to use the NLTK module and tokenize a text.

The first thing I do is open python (through Cygwin or directly from IDLE but I've mostly been using Cygwin).

```
>>>import nltk
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.book import *
```

at which point a library of different books would be downloaded for me to access. I don't really need them, though, because I need to access a local file, in a folder called "Tint"

The command that I HAVE managed to do but cannot replicate is

```
>>>Rev = open("/Users/acer/OneDrive - Università di Pavia/Desktop/Tint/amazon_jamon.no_alterations.txt", "r").read()
```

In the past, the first problem I was experiencing was using the escape command due to back-slash but when I fixed that to regular slashes it would work. Now that I am trying to access a similar .txt file in the same "Tint" folder, through this command I get a different error.

```
>>> desc = open("/Users/acer/OneDrive - Università di Pavia/Desktop/Tint/salame_
P.txt", "r").read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Python 395\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 834: char
acter maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: the python you are using is not a Cygwin one. What type of encode is `salame_P.txt` using ? You can use cygwin `iconv` to covert different encode

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Could you help? @matzeri
What can I do to find out what type of encode "salame_P.txt" is using?
My teacher and instructors just give us code without explaining anything.

I don't understand why I can't repeat what I did even though I did this exact process.

Comment: Python is assuming the file is a windows ASCII file. That is what the `cp1252.py` means. Change your open to `desc = open(file, "r", encoding="utf8")` to tell python the file contains Unicode characters.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Still not sure why I didn't need to make that specification for a similar .txt file but at least now I know how to handle encoding errors. I would vote your comment up but the site doesn't seem to allow me to.